# How to split string number into separate integers

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and programming at all, and I face the following problem.

How to split a given number, which I recieve as a string, to array of integers in console application?

For example: My input is `41234` and I want to turn it to array of "4", "1", "2", "3" and "4".

I've tried to use standard

```
Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

But it sets the whole number as content of the first index of the array, does not splits it.

I've also tried to use char[] array, but in some cases it returns the ASCII value of the char, not the value it represents.

Comment: Don't chain methods together until you're sure you're getting what you expect out of the first one, then the second, and so on. Or at least debug it that way so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: A string is an array of *characters*. You're asking how to convert each of those Char objects into a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) uses whitespace characters as the default separators. This means that `String.Split()` will split along spaces and newlines. It won't return individual characters.

This expression :

```
var ints = "1\n2 345".Split();
```

Will return :

```
1 2 345
```

A string is an `IEnumerable<char>` which means you can process individual characters. A `Char` is essentially an Int32 and digits are ordered. This means you can get their values by subtracting the value of `0`:

```
var ints = "12345".Select(c=>c-'0').ToArray();
```

Or even :

```
var sum="12345".Select(c=>c-'0').Sum();
Debug.Assert(sum==15);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This (c=>c-'0") is new concept for me, I'll investigate it. I've just tryed it - it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return each character as an integer, you can just treat the string as an `IEnumerable<char>` (which it is) and you can use a couple of static methods on the `char` class:

1. [`char.IsNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=netframework-4.8) will return `true` if the character is a number
2. [`char.GetNumericValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8) will return the numeric value of the character (or `-1` for non-numeric characters)

For example:

```
int[] numbers = "123456_ABC"
    .Where(char.IsNumber)  // This is optional if you know they're all numbers
    .Select(c => (int) char.GetNumericValue(c))  // cast here since this returns a double
    .ToArray();
```

Alternatively, since we know non-numeric characters get a `-1` value from `GetNumericValue`, we can do:

```
int[] numbers = "123456_ABC"
    .Select(c => (int) char.GetNumericValue(c))  // cast here since this returns a double
    .Where(value => value != -1)  // This is optional if you know they're all numbers
    .ToArray();
```

In both cases above, `numbers` becomes: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

Answer (score 4):

> but in some cases it returns the ASCII value of the char, not the value it represents.

It *always* does that (a `string` is a sequence of `char`), but if you're only dealing with integers via characters in the range `'0'`-`'9'`, you can fix that via subtraction:

```cs
int[] values = s.Select(c => (int)(c - '0')).ToArray();
```

Comment: plus you made a beauty with this (c - '0') :)

Answer (score 0):

There is much solution in C# for this

```
int[] values = "41234".ToArray().Select(c=> (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm flattered that you copied my answer! But you don't need the first `ToArray`, since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

This Code snapshot will replace all character except numeric to blank and gives you only int array.

```
string a = "1344te12we3ta";
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\D+");
string result = rgx.Replace(a, "");
int[] intA = Array.ConvertAll(result.ToCharArray(), c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
```